# Pulling multiple entries with the same ID in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

Since Google Sheets does not have an `AGGREGATE` function I am unsure how exactly I could do this.

We have a table that looks like this:

```
Hall      Room   Email
Hall2     RoomA  eggmcmuffin@example.com
Hall2     RoomA  brownies@example.com
Hall2     RoomA  nachos@example.com
Hall2     RoomB  hotdog@example.com
Hall3     RoomA  bofa@example.com
...    ...
```

So I would like to create a new table where the user can enter a hall AND room and to the right, it is populated with each email matching that in the big table.

```
Hall               Room                Email
*User enters hall* *User enters room*  *All emails populate*
```

Halls are pulled from a pull-down so it will be an exact match. The emails can exist in either multiple cells or one, I just want it to be an easy copy and paste for me into email later, a semi-colon delimiter could be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("; "; 1; FILTER(C1:C; A1:A=E7; B1:B=F7)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I attempted to replicate this however it doesn't seem to work: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OzVhiDvL1buclrDvHTEXHPqultg9wk2Rr0eAo9gHYyI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: use: `=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, FILTER(Roster!$M$2:$M, Roster!$H$2:$H=A2, Roster!$I$2:$I=B2)))`

Comment: select column B in MRMAs and format it as Plain text. then select column i in roster and do the same

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11czTkZ_Tabdl4_XCHwwKc3vf9rS3eXsqO4fCJKIVM7w/edit#gid=0